# Time increases to update private Observable Collection with each refresh

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, fluent-nhibernate

I have a WPF application using MVVM approach.

In one of my viewmodels I have a private observable collection which I set to a 'new observableCollection' which is created from a query which fetches the data via a repository class using an ISession object from NHibernate.

I have a private observable collection in my viewmodel which I want to update with the collection returned/created from my query.

The problem is, every time I call my method to perform the query, the time taken to update the private object ( ObservableCollection ) takes longer every time.

I tested the time taken for the query to execute in the repository and its only 4 or 5 seconds.. I am retrieving 4500 records using lazy loading.

So my question is why would the time increase every time I call my refresh method in the viewmodel? Additionally I should also add that the memory usage shown in task manager also increases so it almost appears there is a memory leak?

**Code example below:**

ViewModel:

```
private static ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel> _allCustomers;      
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> expression2 = p => p.IsVisible == 'T';

_allCustomers = new ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel>(
    from customer in ManyEntitiesRepository<Customer>.Instance.RetrieveAll(expression2)
    select new CustomerViewModel(customer));
```

**Repository Retrieve**

```
    public virtual IList<T> RetrieveAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_allEntities != null)
            {
                foreach (T entity in _allEntities)
                    SessionProvider.Instance.GlobalSession.Evict(entity);
                _allEntities.Clear();
            }

            _allEntities = (from c in SessionProvider.Instance.GlobalSession.Query<T>().AsExpandable()
                            where expression.Invoke(c)
                            select c).ToList<T>();

            return _allEntities;
        }
```

Comment: What is `SessionProvider.Instance.GlobalSession.Evict(entity);`?

Comment: 'SessionProvider' is the name of my SessionProvider class which creates 1 session for the life of the application, its privately set so that its a singleton, this is the 'Instance'. The Global Session is an 'ISession' object provided by NHibernate which tracks all the objects/entities living in the current scope within the application. So , when I call the RetrieveAll function above, I pass the object type i want to query, in this case its a 'Customer' class type. Before a full retrieve is done on the 'Customer', we need to evict ( get rid of ) the current customers in the global session

Comment: .. if we didnt do the evict then we would have double the amount of customers on top of the already existing customer entities which existed in the globalSession

Comment: Still have had no joy in determining the issue here. Im doing the same query but the time taken to cast the IList<T> to ObservableCollection<T> in the viewmodel is taking longer with every click on the refresh button and as I mentioned the memory consumption increases... anyone have any ideas?

Comment: UPDATE :Hi all, ok, Im pretty sure Ive found the issue with this after hours of trawling blogs, reading similar issues etc .. and taking some good advice on this site to use the ANT .NET Profiler application. I did indeed profile the application and found that when I do a refresh I wanted to create a new observableCollection of viewmodels but substitute the current collection which was bound to a grid view and update it with the new collection. What in fact is happening is that the 1st ObservableCollection bound to the grid doesnt go away and isnt disposed...

Comment: I have a Non-Static ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel> Customers which is bound to a datagrid. When the application loads the datagrid is bound to this collection. But say I want to requery the database to get a fresh set of customers into the collection which is bound to the DataGrid how do i do it without using the 'new ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel>' in my code? As explained above when i do this the original number of viewmodels stay in memory and the same number are created for a second time doubling the number of viewmodels in memory.. does this make sense?

Comment: DOes ViewModels subscribes to some external classes/services events? Events some times cause such leaks

Comment: The viewmodel of which I build a collection of ( 4500 approx ) uses different classes yes. It also uses relaycommands and 'Action' delegates and MVVM messaging ( MVVM Light Toolkit )

Comment: I have done tonnes of testing today. I have concluded that the NHibernate query is not memory intensive. I done 10 consecutive refreshes which executed a query on my ISession object to query the data base ( select query ) it completed in the same time approx all 10 times and the memory was not affected too much. I even tried retrieving a list from the repository using the same query and using a 'ForEach' loop to add each of the viewmodels in my list to a private ObservableCollection which was NOT BOUND to any controls in the view. But still the length of time to build the viewmodels increases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To workaround this I am looping the viewmodels in my private collection and calling cleanup() on each... adds an extra 4 seconds or so to the refresh but hey its better than having your memory clogged up with duplicate viewmodels and having the query time increase by 20 seconds or more with each refresh.

```
                    foreach (XViewModel m in _xCollection)
                    {
                        m.Cleanup();

                     }
```

I will keep an eye out for V.4 of the toolkit release in the coming months...

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ok so as mentioned before, the viewmodels were doubling in size. 
When the application first loads it loaded 4689 records from the database. 
With every refresh done to retrieve a fresh set of data from the database there were another 4689 loaded and so on... and so on. This was pretty massive in terms of memory leakage.

The reason for this happening was I had 2 messages registered in the viewmodel I was creating a collection of where those messages were referencing other viewmodels. The messages although do show up as 'Weak References' when I traced them in Ants Memory profiler but were not releasing the other objects.

Once I delete the 2 references there was no issues. Fast retrieval of data and no memory leak.

```
Messenger.Default.Register<BroadcastPropertyChanged<ControlContainerTemplate>>(this, (message) =>
        {
            //// Instance needs to find out if it is a real receiver
            if (_udfViewModel != null && _udfViewModel.ControlsValue.Any((c) => message.Sender == c))
                RaiseBooleanFlagsChanged();
        });

        Messenger.Default.Register<BroadcastPropertyChanged<ChargeTemplateViewModel>>(this, (message) =>
            {
                //// Instance needs to find out if it is a real receiver
                if (_chargeTemplates != null && _chargeTemplates.Any((c) => message.Sender == c))
                    RaiseBooleanFlagsChanged();
});
```

I am using the Galasoft.MVVM Light Toolkit... where it states that the messages dont need disposed as they are weak references but now I am obviously going to have to look for an alternative to have my viewmodels communicate, or am going to have to see how to unregister those messages before creating a new collection of that viewmodel.

On checking out :http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/ , Laurant has identified this problem which I am only seeing now :) but he is looking to fix this issue in MVVM Light toolkit in version 4 so as that the weak reference actually is a weak reference and the viewmodels can be released and collected by the GC.

Thanks